# How to add image file to sketch in intelliJ

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to use processing in IntelliJ and I'm having trouble importing/running an image file. The console is saying that the file cannot be reached because it is not in my sketch. What is a sketch and how do I add a file to it?

I've made sure the file name is right so I don't think that is the issue.

```java
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;

public class image2 extends PApplet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("image2");
    }

    public void settings() {
        size(1920, 1080);
    }
    PImage photo;

    public void setup() {
        size(1920, 1080);
        photo =  loadImage("testimage.jpg");
    }
    public void draw(){}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your image in the data folder and use [`dataPath()`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#dataPath-java.lang.String-)

```
photo =  loadImage(dataPath("testimage.jpg"));
```

(alternatively use [`sketchPath()`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#sketchPath-java.lang.String-) `photo =  loadImage(sketchPath("testimage.jpg"));`)

(Your issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000598/error-message-the-file-countries-geo-json-is-missing-or-inaccessible/54048109#54048109))

Comment: Thanks! This really helped and I’ll try this.